# Iterm2 : how to display status bar

Tags: iterm2, iterm

In the [Iterm2 online docs](https://www.iterm2.com/3.3/documentation-status-bar.html):

> Go to Preferences > Profiles > Session. Turn on Status bar enabled.

but I don't find this setting in the preference pane:
[Preferences screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGdKY.png)

Obviously the version is up to date 3.2.8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The status bar is a new feature as of iTerm2 3.3.0, which is currently available as a test release -> https://www.iterm2.com/downloads.html

Comment: Hi, how to change the position of the status to bottom?

Comment: @BinhBui Prefs > Appearance > General > Status Bar Location